# Section background color covers row

Tags: html, css

I created a section with a row and some content. Here is the code:

```css
#one-third-img-two-third-text8 { 
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 50px; 
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/10/09/clouds-5784152_960_720.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: left top; 
    position: relative; 
    } 
    #one-third-img-two-third-text8::before { 
    background-color: rgba(9, 127, 113, 0.76);
    content: ""; height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: -50px; 
    } 
    #one-third-img-two-third-text8 .otittt-container { 
    background-color: rgb(1, 30, 34); 
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 25px; 
    padding-bottom: 25px; 
    padding-right: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="one-third-img-two-third-text8"> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row otittt-container"> 
            <div class="col-lg-4"> 
                <div class="product-img d-flex justify-content-center"> 
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/10/09/clouds-5784152_960_720.jpg" class="img-fluid"> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-8"> 
                <div class="content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
                    </p> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

I added a before pseudo element so I can add a color overlay on top of the section background image. But the color overlay also covers the row. How can I make sure the color overlay stays behind the row and not cover it? I tried to play with z-index, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to do this with z-index, you need to add it to 2 different places to get the order right.  Take a look:

```css
#one-third-img-two-third-text8 { 
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 50px; 
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/10/09/clouds-5784152_960_720.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: left top; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index:1;
    } 
    #one-third-img-two-third-text8::before { 
    background-color: rgba(9, 127, 113, 0.76);
    content: ""; height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: -50px; 
    z-index: -1;
    } 
    #one-third-img-two-third-text8 .otittt-container { 
    background-color: rgb(1, 30, 34); 
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 25px; 
    padding-bottom: 25px; 
    padding-right: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="one-third-img-two-third-text8"> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row otittt-container"> 
            <div class="col-lg-4"> 
                <div class="product-img d-flex justify-content-center"> 
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/10/09/clouds-5784152_960_720.jpg" class="img-fluid"> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-8"> 
                <div class="content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
                    </p> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```